# How to left join count?

Tags: database, sqlite

```
select DISTINCT(cctv_id), cctv.[name] from points_cctv left join cctv on points_cctv.[cctv_id] = cctv.[id]
```

I want to count number of records in `points_cctv` where `points_cctv.[cctv_id] = cctv.[id]` and show this as additional column in the above query. When I insert `count(points_cctv.[cctv_id])` it will give me just one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cctv_id, cctv.[name], count(cctv_id)
from points_cctv left join cctv on points_cctv.[cctv_id] = cctv.[id]
group by cctv_id, cctv.name
```

Comment: is there any way to show also those rows from `cctv` table which doesn't have corresponding rows in `points_cctv` table?